# In Scala, how do I create a new function by setting one argument in another function to the value of a variable?

Tags: function, scala, closures

Here's my failed attempt at doing what I'd like to do:

```
var currentNum = 0
def adder = (x:Int, y:Int) => x+y
def getNumAdder = {x: Int =>
  val currentNumSnapshot = currentNum
  adder(x, currentNumSnapshot)
}
currentNum = 5
val addFive = getNumAdder
currentNum = 9
val addNine = getNumAdder

println("10 plus 5 is "+addFive(10))
println("10 plus 9 is "+addNine(10))
```

":paste" that in the Scala REPL and you'll get this:

```
10 plus 5 is 19
10 plus 9 is 19
```

I want to be able to call getNumAdder and get a function that adds a snapshot of the current value to an inputted number.  What can I change to get the desired behavior?

UPDATE:

As per the warnings promoting referential transparency, I believe this code, a simple example of currying in Scala, does what I need as well.

```
var currentNum = 0
def adder(x:Int) = (y:Int) => x+y
def getNumAdder(input: Int) = {
  adder(input)
}
currentNum = 5
val addFive = getNumAdder(currentNum)
```

Comment: I thought that it's not a good practice to write code like this. It's depending on the context and is not referential transparent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def getNumAdder = {
  val currentNumSnapshot = currentNum
  adder((_: Int), currentNumSnapshot) // or (x: Int) => adder(x, currentNumSnapshot)
}
```

Note that it has to be a `def`, not a `val`, so that `currentNumSnapshot` is evaluated every time `getNumAdder` is called.

Note that

```
{x: Int =>
  val currentNumSnapshot = currentNum
  adder(x, currentNumSnapshot)
}
```

is quite different from

```
{
  val currentNumSnapshot = currentNum
  (x: Int) => adder(x, currentNumSnapshot)
}
```

In my version when `getNumAdder` is evaluated, I first save the current value of `currentNum` and then return the function which uses this snapshot. In your version the entire block is the function which is returned, so the line `val currentNumSnapshot = currentNum` is only executed when the function is called (e.g. `addFive(10)`) and so obviously uses the value of `currentNum` at that time.

And as goral notes, it's usually a bad idea to do something like that in real code, I am assuming this is only done for understanding.

Comment: This unfortunately doesn't seem to be working, but maybe my not-exact testing in the REPL is at fault.  It didn't like the _ ... said there was no type for the input parameter... so I passed in x:Int instead, and that worked.  But the main problem is, the functions I create before and after the changing of the var both add the last number I set it to.

Comment: Updated my question with code you can easily paste into a REPL to see what's going on.  Thanks either way.

Comment: Thanks, and nice to see how this is done finally!  This is actually a simplification of something going into real code, potentially.  The single-argument method of an existing component stores and later executes functions, and I need that function to behave differently each time, based on an initial action.  The "currentNum" takes the place of the variable storing the initial action.  I'd have modified the storing method to accept another argument, but it's dangerous to break existing code at this point.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this one satisfy you but it's working:

```
  var currentNum = 0                              //> currentNum  : Int = 0
  def adder = (x: Int, y: Int) => x + y           //> adder: => (Int, Int) => Int
  val getNumAdder = { x: Int =>
    val currentNumSnapshot = currentNum
    println(currentNumSnapshot)
    adder(x, currentNumSnapshot)                  //> getNumAdder  : Int => Int = <function1>
  }

  def curriedAdder = adder.curried                //> curriedAdder: => Int => (Int => Int)
  currentNum = 5
  val addFive = curriedAdder(currentNum)          //> addFive  : Int => Int = <function1>
  currentNum = 9
  val addNine = curriedAdder(currentNum)          //> addNine  : Int => Int = <function1>

  println("10 plus 5 is " + addFive(10))          //> 10 plus 5 is 15
  println("10 plus 9 is "+addNine(10))            //> 10 plus 9 is 19
```

Comment: you're not even using `getNumAdder` anymore, and you're just passing the value of `currentNum` explicitly—how is that related to what was asked?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are capturing the value of `currentNum` when the function is called and not when it is created. Sou you must change it to:

```
var currentNum = 0
def adder = (x:Int, y:Int) => x + y
def getNumAdder = {
  val currentNumSnapshot = currentNum
  x: Int => adder(x, currentNumSnapshot)
}
currentNum = 5
val addFive = getNumAdder
currentNum = 9
val addNine = getNumAdder
```

This will work as expected:

```
scala> println("10 plus 5 is "+addFive(10))
10 plus 5 is 15

scala> println("10 plus 9 is "+addNine(10))
10 plus 9 is 19
```